# Slow webapp load time in Safari iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

Our webapp takes approximately 30 seconds to load for the first time in Safari on iOS 9.1.  Most of the visual loading happens in a timely manner, but HTTP requests cannot be handled for about 30 seconds.  I have only been able to reproduce this on an iPad by going to the following link: http://tco.ekotrope.com/tco/?deployment=eko-dev&#community/default.  And I can only reproduce it once, due to caching.  It can be reproduced another time by going to the following link, http://tco.ekotrope.com/tco/?deployment=eko-dev&#community/sunwood-bridgewater.

I have tried investigating looking at the Developer Tools Network Tab while the iPad is plugged into a Macbook, but for some odd reason, the page loads quickly when it's plugged in and I'm looking at the Network Tab.

Any ideas what could be going on or what I could do for further investigation?  Thanks!

Comment: I am also running into this issue, but I noticed the links you posted do not seem to have the issue anymore. Did you happen to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: It looks like this issue also affects iOS 9

Comment: I'm having the same issue, some page resources just stall for around 30 seconds. Most of the times it's a css file, but when accessing via computer it works flawless.

Comment: Apparently the problem occurs on WiFi. On 3G/4G the requests don't stall more than 10 seconds, at most. The latency should be smaller on WiFi but apparently there is something going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to resolve the problem on our webapp.

In a nutshell, the problem is with how iOS 9.1 Safari chooses to schedule HTTP connections. For reasons probably related to increasing performance in certain cases has caused certain edge-cases to become problematic. In our case we had several images trying to load at the same time as we needed an XHR to occur. In other browsers like desktop Chrome this was not an issue, but iOS 9.1 Safari chokes when it tries to do all of that at once. Our solution was to have the images that trigger the problem load one after the other rather than all at the same time. This spread things out enough that things operated smoothly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but need some clarification on how your images were originally loading before you applied the fix. Did you just have the images embedded directly as `<img>` elements, and the fact that they were all loading at once is what caused Safari to choke? And what about *after* the fix? I'm guessing you used JavaScript to moderate / queue the loading of the images? Not looking for code examples, so don't worry about digging anything up -- just curious about the process you used.

Comment: I second the request for some clarification.  I have a site that scores a 90 on yslow and loads fine on all browsers and devices except for iOS devices and safari but only over wifi, over LTE it loads fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response!  We have the images stored on Amazon S3 so they are loaded dynamically, but we were loading them all at once.  As part of the fix we used this preloadr plugin: https://github.com/OneGeek/preloadr.